# Detect nonsharp object on complex background

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have to detect an object on video. Here is one of its [frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbuTS.jpg), and [the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE2mn.jpg). 
The problem is in a very complex, multicolored (including object color) and multipatterned background.
I've tried to simplify the frame with HSV mask ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BacAN.jpg)), but it didn't helped much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried template matching?